# OpenCV - obtaining smooth part of oblong shape after thresholding

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, image-thresholding

I am doing thresholding on an image and I achieve this result: [image after thresholding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJKel.png).

Now I would like to achieve only  the contour of the biggest oblong shape:
[oblong shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WE6f.png).

What is the best way to achieve it with OpenCV? I know that the shape has some offshoots. Is there a possibility to get rid of them?

Comment: If your "oblong shape" is always significantly thicker than the offshoots - simply dilate the image until they "fall off", then find the biggest contour.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you invert the thresholded image so that the contours are white and the background is black ( `cv2.threshold(cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`). Then you search for contours with `cv2.findContours()`. To select your desirable contour you can make some filters to eliminate other contours from the contour you are hoping to find. You can use the filters in a For loop ( `for i in contours:` ) and with some conditional statements for the filters. For filters you can try the size of contours ( `size = cv2.contourArea(i)` )   or height and width ( `x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(i)` ). Then you can make the statements like `if size > 100 and h > 100 and w < 50: cv2.drawContours()`. Hope it gives you an idea on how to proceed. Cheers!

Comment: or you can check which contour is the biggest.